# \PassOptionsToClass does not work

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I am trying to create my own class, inheriting from `extarticle`.

I want to still be able to use the options of this class, so I found a way to do it in most of the docs I read :

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Unfortunately, that does not work. I don't understand since a lot of docs are suggesting to do that.

Even if I try to hardcode the command, nothing happens :

```
\PassOptionsToClass{14pt}{extarticle}
```

The only way to have the options read by `extarticle` seems to be by hardcoding them during the loadclass command (which is not what I want) :

```
\LoadClass[14pt,english]{extarticle}
```

My class is doing nothing so far, just the minimum :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{base}[2017/12/19 base class]

\LoadClass{extarticle}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `\LoadClass` statement is written too early here: The derived class must process the options first and is instructed to hand over the unknown options (i.e. those that are not defined by the derived class) to the base class afterwards with `\DeclareOption*`, then load the base class.

**Class code -- changed a little bit to allow for easy change of the base class**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{extbase}[2017/12/19 base class]

\def\extbase@baseclass{extarticle}

\DeclareOption{myoption}{\typeout{This is a nice option}}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\extbase@baseclass}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{\extbase@baseclass}
```

Please note that `\LoadClassWithOptions{extarticle}` instead of `\LoadClass{extarticle}` would not be useful here since it would not recognize options that are defined within the derived class, as a consequence LaTeX complains about unknown options.

**Some testing code**

```
\documentclass[14pt,myoption]{extbase}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

**Wrong example with `\LoadClassWithOptions`** -- the output below shows that LaTeX warns about `myoption` being unknown to `extarticle`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{extbasewrong}[2017/12/19 base class]

\def\extbase@baseclass{extarticle}

\DeclareOption{myoption}{\typeout{This is a nice option}}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\extbase@baseclass}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClassWithOptions{\extbase@baseclass}
```

Output:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
>
> (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
>
> (./clsloaderwrong.tex LaTeX2e <2017-04-15> Babel <3.15> and
>
> hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded. (./extbasewrong.cls
>
> Document Class: extbasewrong 2017/12/19 base class This is a nice
>
> option )
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes/extarticle.cls
>
> Document Class: extarticle 1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document
>   class
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes/size14.clo)
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/exscale.sty))
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
>
> LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
>
> ```
> [myoption].
> ```
>
> (./clsloaderwrong.aux)
>
> [1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/up
>
> dmap/pdftex.map}] (./clsloaderwrong.aux)
>
> ) Output written on
>
> clsloaderwrong.pdf (1 page, 14840 bytes). Transcript written on
>
> clsloaderwrong.log.

Comment: @Sylver: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!